# Series of need(validate) in Shiny: Printing only the first case of failure

Tags: r, shiny, user-input, numeric

I am trying to create a Shiny app that has a user-specified input for p-value (should be a probability between 0 and 1). Before, I have had the user specify p-value using the [`sliderInput()`](https://shiny.rstudio.com/tutorial/written-tutorial/lesson3/) function.

However, I find that the resolution is limited with `sliderInput()`. It is difficult for me to allow a user to define values like 0.001 versus 0.0000000001 and still use larger values like 0.4. As a result, I am not trying to allow users to input their p-value in a much more flexible manner using the Shiny `textInput()`. Then, they can easily type in values like 0.0000000001 or 1e-20 or 0.2 without frustratingly trying to move the slider perfectly only to find that such resolutions do not exist.

I *think* I have a working MWE. I am using the `validate(need)` format to guide users should they input something nonsensical. It may just be a finer detail, but currently, if a user types in a value of something like "hello", they get all three `validate(need)` messages from the application:

```
'P-value must be a decimal between 0 and 1.'
'P-value must be less than or equal to 1.'
'P-value must be greater than or equal to 0.'
```

**My question is:** Is it possible to tweak this code so that only the first `validate(need)` that fails gets printed? If there are other foreseeable problems related to using `textInput()` instead of sliderInput() despite working with numbers, feel free to share too. Thank you for your advice!

**My MWE:**

```
if (interactive()) {
    options(device.ask.default = FALSE)

    ui <- fluidPage(
        textInput("PValue", "P-value:", value = "0.05"),
        plotOutput('plot')
    )

    server <- function(input, output) {
        output$plot <- renderPlot({
            cat(str(input$PValue))

            validate(
                need(!is.na(as.numeric(input$PValue)), 'P-value must be a decimal between 0 and 1.'),
                need(as.numeric(input$PValue) <= 1, 'P-value must be less than or equal to 1.'),
                need(as.numeric(input$PValue) >= 0, 'P-value must be greater than or equal to 0.')
            )

            plot(input$PValue)
        })
        p
    }
    shinyApp(ui, server)
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could separate the three conditions:

```
validate(need(is.numeric(input$PValue), 'P-value must be a decimal between 0 and 1.'))
validate(need(as.numeric(input$PValue) <= 1, 'P-value must be less than or equal to 1.')),
validate(need(as.numeric(input$PValue) >= 0, 'P-value must be greater than or equal to 0.'))
```

shiny then checks the individual conditions one after the other and displays only an error message.